# Apache tomcat setup

Tags: jsp, tomcat7, tomcat

I think this could be my first question here in stackoverflow.

It's about as simple as setting up tomcat server. I downloaded Tomcat 7 yesterday, unzipped and run the 'start'. For some strange reason, when I try to open "http://localhost:8080" it is redirecting me to the "GlassFish Enterprise Server".

I am not sure when I've installed GlassFish server (may be I did it long ago). I tried to stop it by using the commands necessary, from this url:

http://thedata.org/book/start-and-stop-glassfish-server

but it doesn't stop.

Can someone please help me in setting up Tomcat server ?

Thank you very much.

a bit off topic :
All I want is a server environment (At my home) so that I can practice server-scripting programming like JSP, Servlets and so on, if anyone can help me in setting up a free server side 'eclipse' environment, that would be great, I appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glassfish is part of the Java EE SDK download. Probably you downloaded and installed Java EE SDK while being ignorant that it's actually a software bundle which includes the Glassfish application server, the Netbeans IDE (optionally) and several documentation/examples.

Likely you installed Glassfish as a Windows Service which causes that it's always started whenever you start Windows. Apart from turning it off by the Service Manager, I'd just uninstall the Java EE SDK by the control panel. You don't need it if you just want to go ahead with Eclipse+Tomcat.

As to learning JSP/Servlets, I'd suggest to use our wiki pages as a starting point.

- [JSP info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)
- [Servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

At the bottom you can find links to [Coreservlets.com](http://coreservlets.com) tutorials, they cover learning JSP/Servlets using the Eclipse+Tomcat combination.

Comment: Thank you very much for those links, they almost solved what I needed. Yes, it seems that I have Java EE SDK installed, so I uninstall-ed it, but strangely even after that, "http://localhost:8080/" directs me to GlassFish Server.

Anyways I got Tomcat Server running after following the Eclipse+Tomcat installation from your links. (though had few glitches in eclipse installation bcuz of 64-bit windows, I re-solved it anyways).

Thanks again @BalusC

Answer (score 0):

You can always change the tomcat port.
Locate the file $TOMCAT_HOME\conf\server.xml"
Replace `<Connector port="8080"` with `<Connector port="8081"` for example.
Start tomcat and test it at http://localhost:8081.

Cheers,

Comment: And you can configure Eclipse Helios to use it by Going to Java EE Perspective / Servers View / Right Click / New / Apache / Tomcat 7 / follow the wizard. Now you can start / stop and publish your web projects through Eclipse.

Comment: I knew this a year before, but I forgot. Thanks for reminding me, but strangely it did not work.

but this worked (port 8081 or port 8082) after I did the Eclipse+Tomcat installation from the link provided by BalusC.

Thank you Anthony.

Now I should go hunt an open-source 'free' database to link with my server.

Comment: Hi @Prashanth, I'm glad to help (and curious about why it didn't work, but nevermind). As for a good database for developer needs, I would recommend H2 (http://www.h2database.com/). Fast, simple, standard, and reliable (against all odds for a database this size). Cheers